# Where Do You Store Data in a GUI Application?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've always heard that you should separate GUI/Data/Logic components, like the MVC pattern.
So, I am wondering: In a GUI application, where do you actually store the data?

Here is an example (using C# terminology):
Suppose you have a GUI that takes user input, does some analysis, and displays results in a table.
 The user can have several analyses in one window, so there is a ListView at the bottom that allows the user to select which analysis is currently displayed (the selected item gets displayed).

In order to display this, the analysis data must be stored somewhere.
 I have always done one of two things:

1. Put all the data into a single object and store it in the ListViewItem's "Tag" property
2. Extend "ListViewItem" and just add whatever properties I need.

But, this means I am storing the data inside of the ListViewItem.
Is there a more appropriate place to keep track of the data?

I could add it as private members to the main form, but that seems like the same thing.
The only other thing I can think of is to make some global class that I can reference whenver I need to.

Thanks.

Comment: Am I correct to assume, that you are talking only about temporary storage - the data that only exists while application is running and no persistence whatsoever ?

Comment: @tereško Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have some ListViewItems. Each ListViewItem is associated with your business logic object and after select one of ListViewItem you want make some operations over this buisness object. In similar situations I usually make Data Object like

```
struct MyDataObject
{
   string Id;//very often data object need to have Identifcator, but not always
   //some fields
}
```

and add to data object constructors for typical user input.

After that I make business logic layer contains available algorithms for this data objects. For simple projects, this is a static class like

```
static class MyDataObjectOperationService{
    void MakeSomething(MyDataObject myDataObject);
    object GetSomething(MyDataObject myDataObject);
    ...
}
```

For big projects that is usually `interface`. Also I usually make a data layer `interface` for getting this data object. For example

```
interface IMyDataObjectRepository{
  IList<MyDataObject> GetAll();  
  MyDataObject GetById(string id);
  //CRUD operations if it need
}
```

After that I put into ListViewItems ids of Data Objects and on ListViewItemClick getting selecting id, after that getting DataObject by Id using data layer classes and  make some operations using business logic layer classes. If I need to save DataObject changes or create new DataObject I using data layer classes.